# Multiple Integration (with Scipy or otherwise)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Let `f` be a real-valued python function of a single vector argument `x`, defined so that `x` could have a variety of lengths. I want to numerically integrate `f` over (a subset of) all `x` of length `m`, where `m` is some fixed positive integer. `scipy.integrate.nquad` seems like a good option for numerical integration in several variables, however, it requires the input function `f` to be defined as a function of `m` arguments, e.g. `def f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_m): ...` rather than `def f(x): ...`. (I assume that `scipy` requires this because it deduces the number of variables of integration from `argspec` or something similar.) How can I obtain such a function from my function `f(x)`? (I'd like to be able to do this for several "large" values of `m`, so doing it "by hand" is not an acceptable answer.)

I'd also be open to better alternatives to `scipy.integrate.nquad`.

Comment: So you are integrating over a subset of `x_n`, while varying another subset.  Use `quad` or `nquad` on the integration variables, and use the `args` parameter to pass the other ones - one case at a time.  You've got to iterate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use starargs, scipy will infer the number of arguments from the integration limits. Trivial example:

```
from scipy import integrate
def f(*args):
    x, y, z = args
    return x*y*z

integrate.nquad(f,[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]])
# (0.12499999999999999, 5.527033708952211e-15)
```

So you can simply wrap your function:

```
def g(*args):
    return f(np.asanyarray(args))
```